# installed libapache2-mod_fastcgi on debian 7 - no php5-fcgi file

Tags: php5, mod-fastcgi

So I install Apache2 worker with libapache2-mod-fastcgi (non-free) on my Debian server.

I found this snippet from the web, however, I don't have anything in my /usr/lib/cgi-bin/ folder. So how is my php working when I view phpinfo() ???

```
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
AddHandler php5-fcgi .php
Action php5-fcgi /php5-fcgi
Alias /php5-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi
FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi -socket /var/run/php5-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

FastCGI allows you to run PHP separately from your server. Your server connects to PHP workers through sockets. The snippet you referenced doesn't relate to your specific configuration.